# Checking if a string contains a regex in the form of a date in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string variable defined as :

```
string str = Request[columns[2][search]];
```

Sometimes the `str` returns me a value of `AR` and sometimes `15/02/2018 to 23/04/2018`

Therefore I am checking if the `str` contains `15/02/2018 to 23/04/2018`, then it should return me true.

To perform this check I have used the below code, which does not seem to work. It always returns me `false`. Can someone please help me with this or by using a regex as an alternative ?

```
 DateTime date;

 Boolean isValidDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "dd/MM/yyyy to dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
```

Comment: So will it always be exactly "[date] to [date]"? And is the format always dd/MM/yyyy?

Comment: @JonSkeet : Yes, the format will always be in `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: @john : Yeah. It is just a string variable.

Comment: Note that "t" and "o" have [special meanings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) here. You also can't parse two different dates as one.

Comment: @john : Even if I parse it like `"dd/MM/yyyy 'to' dd/MM/yyyy"` it does not work.

Comment: Of course not, `t` is AM or PM, and `o` is the ISO8601 format.

Comment: @john: You missed the fact that the OP quoted the `'to'` in that string. It doesn't work for a different reason, namely that it's trying to parse two dates at the same time, rather than one. (`o` only has any specific meaning as a single character format string too)

Comment: @Jon Oh, you're quite right. I didn't notice the addition of the quotes. Oddly enough, parsing two dates ("dd/MM/yyyy dd/MM/yyyy", for example) does seem to work, but only if the dates are identical. I wonder why it doesn't simply get thrown out. That's probably a topic for another discussion though :)

Answer (score 4):

I would do this in two passes:

- Use a regular expression to extract the dates if they're present at all.
- Use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to check that each date really is a date.

I would recommend against trying to do full date validation in the regular expression itself - that's more in the `DateTime` domain. The regular expression domain is more "finding the bit of text that *might* be a date".

Here's a complete example of this approach:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test("AR");
        Test("99/99/9999 to 99/99/9999");
        Test("15/02/2018 to 23/04/2018");
    }

    static void Test(string text)
    {
        var result = TryParseDates(text, out var from, out var to);
        Console.WriteLine(result 
            ? $"{text}: match! From={from:yyyy-MM-dd}; To={to:yyyy-MM-dd}"
            : $"{text}: no match");
    }    

    static readonly Regex dateToDatePattern = new Regex(@"^(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}) to (\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})$");

    static bool TryParseDates(string text, out DateTime from, out DateTime to)
    {
        var match = dateToDatePattern.Match(text);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            // Don't assign values to the out parameters until we know they're
            // both valid.
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(match.Groups[1].Value, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var tempFrom)
                &&
                DateTime.TryParseExact(match.Groups[2].Value, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var tempTo))
            {
                from = tempFrom;
                to = tempTo;
                return true;
            }
        }
        // Either the regex or the parsing failed. Either way, set
        // the out parameters and return false.
        from = default(DateTime);
        to = default(DateTime);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
AR: no match
99/99/9999 to 99/99/9999: no match
15/02/2018 to 23/04/2018: match! From=2018-02-15; To=2018-04-23
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: How can I preserve a value in a string variable and change the value of the variable only if a condition is true ?

Comment: @ExpertGenie: That sounds like you should ask it with more details in a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a method to parse and validate the dates:

```
public bool TryParseDates(string dateString, out DateTime date1, out DateTime date2)
{
    var parts = dateString.Split(new [] { " to " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (parts.Length != 2)
    {
        date1 = default(DateTime);
        date2 = default(DateTime);
        return false;
    }
    var date1Result = DateTime.TryParseExact(parts[0], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date1);
    var date2Result = DateTime.TryParseExact(parts[1], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date2);
    return date1Result && date2Result;
}
```

This splits the strings by " to ", checks that you have two items, and then parses eat date individually, and returns true if it was successful.

Usage:

```
DateTime d1, d2;
bool isValid = TryParseDates(str, out d1, out d2);
```

Sample: http://rextester.com/WCEYI66887

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: How can I preserve a value in a string variable and change the value of the variable only if a condition is true ?